# Android OBB file not found for secondary user in Lock task mode(EMM)

Tags: android, emm, android-multiple-users

In **Android Enterprise management** admin user can access **OBB file** and can open Angry-birds2 app. But for the secondary user OBB file not accessible. For the secondary user got stuck while try to access the OBB file.

How can I share the OBB file with the secondary user? Try to create directory and copy the files but doesn't work.

Note: Admin user working fine, but when switching to secondary user only than I am having issues.

```
                            if (obbFiles.isNotEmpty()) {
                                // Create obb dir
                                val obbDirFile = context.obbDir.parentFile
                                obbDirFile?.run {
                                    if (!exists()) mkdir()
                                }

                                val obbPackageDirFile =
                                    File("${obbDirFile?.path}/${app.packageName}")
                                if (!obbPackageDirFile.exists()) obbPackageDirFile.mkdir()

                                obbFiles.forEach {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "copying obb $it for ${app.packageName}")
                                    val pfd = loanManagerService?.openFile(it)
                                    val ins = ParcelFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream(pfd)
                                    context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(Uri.parse(it))?.use { os ->
                                        ins.copyTo(os)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

Opening the app:
**testOpenAngryBirds2()**

```
    fun testOpenAngryBirds2() {

        Log.d(TAG, " testOpenAngryBirds2: ????????")
        val permissions: List<AppPermission> = listOf()

        val appInfo = AppInfo(
            id = 259,
            name = "Angry Birds 2",
            packageName = "com.rovio.baba",
            description = "Play the Angry Birds game enjoyed by millions of players every day!",
            lockTaskMode = false,
            permissions = permissions,
            highlighted = true
        )

        deviceManager.setPermissionGrantState(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        deviceManager.setPermissionGrantState(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            deviceManager.setPermissionGrantState(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
        }
        deviceManager.setLockTaskPackages(listOf(appInfo))

        deviceManager.openApp(appInfo.packageName, appInfo.lockTaskMode)
    }
```